# Listing MODX Articles with at least one common tag

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-getresources, modx-snippets, modx-template-varaiables

Is it possible to use the getResources snippet to find related articles that have at least one common tag with the active resource?

```
[[getResources? 
        &parents=`xxx, xxx` 
        &showHidden=`1` 
        &limit=`10` 
        &tpl=`relatedArticle-tpl`  
        &depth=`1` 
        &includeContent=`1`
        &includeTVs=`1`
        &processTVs=`1`
        &sortby=`publishedon`
        &tvFilters=`something here` 
]]
```

The TV [[*articletags]] of the active resource should contain at least one common tag with a matching resource.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way how I implemented question:

```
[[getResources? 
    &parents=`x,x` 
    &showHidden=`1` 
    &limit=`10` 
    &tpl=`latestArticle`  
    &depth=`1` 
    &includeContent=`1`
    &includeTVs=`1`
    &resources=`-[[*id]]`
    &processTVs=`0`
    &sortby=`publishedon`
    &tvFilters=`[[tvFilterForRelatedArticles]]`
]]
```

And the snippet to make a TV filter:

```
$tags = $modx->resource->getTVValue('articlestags');
$categories = $modx->resource->getTVValue('category');
$tagsArray = explode(",", $tags);
$categoriesArray = explode(",", $categories);
$result = "";
foreach ($tagsArray as $tag) 
    $result .= "articlestags==%".$tag."%||";
foreach ($categoriesArray as $category) 
    $result .= "category==%".$category."%||";
return substr($result, 0, -1);
```

Not sure if this is the simplest way to achieve my target. Feel free to comment if there is a better solution.